# Replication with fail over cluster in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

Presently I am Using Replication Feature in SQL Server 2012 .I want to migrate to SQL server 2014 .I want to use fail over cluster feature .Does it effect the replication feature which we are using for our project

Answer (score 1):

> Yes you can upgrade without affecting current features .

To upgrade a SQL Server failover cluster to SQL Server 2014, you must run setup with upgrade action on each failover cluster node, one at a time, starting with the passive nodes. As you upgrade each node, it is left out of the possible owners of the failover cluster. If there is an unexpected failover, the upgraded nodes do not participate in the failover until cluster resource group ownership is moved to an upgraded node by SQL Server Setup.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191295.aspx)

Comment: suppose we have three servers with replication such that if one server is busy ,it will hit the other server in our project ...for these we are using sql server 2012 ..now we want to use fail over cluster in our project using sql server 2014 ...can we go with these feature such that it won't affect the replication and we should be able to use primary ,secondary & listener for all three servers

Comment: @pradeepkumaralugurthi: No. In a failover cluster instance (FCI), there is only one instance of the SQL server which can be live on one (and only one) of the machines in the Windows cluster at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading SQL Server is an easy process, the Replication in SQL Server 2014 is supported same way as it is supported in SQL Server 2012. I would advise you to run SQL Server Migration Assistant (formerly, SSUA) and check if there is any path block for the upgrade and also recommend do a test run in dev/test environment. 
In addition to what Tharif has said above, please refer the post from Amit Banerjee at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/upgrading-a-replication-topology-to-sql-server-2016/.

In your second comment you have mentioned using Primary, Secondary and Listener, are you on AG? In that case, you can take advantage of using readable secondary where you can redirect your read-only intent traffic i.e. Reports.